# Split and enumerate sequence elements in R based on previous and next values

Tags: r, dplyr

This problem is getting me insane. Say I have this sequence in a boolean vector:

```
switch <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, rep(FALSE, 6), TRUE, rep(FALSE, 7), TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

And `threshold = 5`

I basically need to group all TRUE values falling into an interval less or equal the threshold (ahead and behind) with an unique setID. When a TRUE value is met, the counter is reset and this allow the set to expand. In other words, I need this output:

```
row | VALUE | SET
----+-------+-------
1   | TRUE  | set_1
2   | TRUE  | set_1
3   | FALSE | 
4   | TRUE  | set_1
5   | FALSE | 
6   | FALSE | 
7   | FALSE | 
8   | FALSE | 
9   | FALSE | 
10  | FALSE | 
11  | TRUE  | set_2 # A new set is created since the last TRUE value was found in the fourth row and 4 + 'threshold' < 11
12  | FALSE | 
13  | FALSE | 
14  | FALSE | 
15  | FALSE | 
16  | FALSE | 
17  | FALSE | 
18  | FALSE |
19  | TRUE  | set_3
20  | TRUE  | set_3
21  | FALSE | 
22  | TRUE  | set_3 # Any TRUE value until 22 + 'threshold' = 27 would be put into the set_3
```

Although this looks trivial at first, I was not able to find an efficient way to do it in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired output does not match up with the data that you provided, so I'm not entirely sure what you want, but here is an attempt.

```
# construct data
dat <- data.frame(switch=switch, set=NA_integer_)

# get the groupings
dat$set[switch] <- cumsum(c(1, diff(which(switch)) > 5))
```

This returns

```
dat
   switch set
1    TRUE   1
2    TRUE   1
3   FALSE  NA
4    TRUE   1
5   FALSE  NA
6   FALSE  NA
7   FALSE  NA
8   FALSE  NA
9   FALSE  NA
10  FALSE  NA
11   TRUE   2
12  FALSE  NA
13  FALSE  NA
14  FALSE  NA
15  FALSE  NA
16  FALSE  NA
17  FALSE  NA
18  FALSE  NA
19   TRUE   3
20  FALSE  NA
21  FALSE  NA
22  FALSE  NA
23  FALSE  NA
24  FALSE  NA
25  FALSE  NA
26   TRUE   4
27   TRUE   4
28  FALSE  NA
29   TRUE   4
```

Comment: Sure thing. One liners are an SO tradition.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `rle`

```
(NA^!switch) * with(rle(switch), rep(cumsum(lengths > 5 & !values), lengths) + 1) 
#[1]  1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  4 NA  4
```

#### data

```
switch <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,   
TRUE)
```